# Objective C - Check running processes

Tags: ios, cordova, process

good afternoon, I'm developing for iOS using phonegap, but I need to modify some objective C code and I was looking for information, but I cant found anything about how to check the amount of running processes in the device (iphone or ipad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no public APIs for this. The reason is that Apple probably doesn't want you doing it, because it violates their app-sandboxing philosophy. And really, there's no reason for you to do it in an AppStore app, because you are guaranteed to be more-or-less the only app running *when you are running*. There may be some music players or VOIP apps in the background, but they user probably wants them there, they are not pertinent to your app, and there's nothing you can do about them anyway.

What is the reason you want to list the running processes on the device?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the reason is because I write a log file with this, and in case of the app crashes due to memory issue, the log register how many apps are running, i did it in android but i cant find how in iOS.

Comment: @Conchitabh You're welcome! You can't do it in iOS, and other apps memory usage isn't really a concern.  You can only control your app's memory usage. Both Android iOS closely monitor system memory usage and give preference to the the currently running app - other app's memory usage shouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: Oh thanks, yes in iOS we dont have problems, in android sometimes the app crashes for memory issues.